# not sure what this date expression does

Tags: sql, date, expression, teradata

I inherited a report that has the following line of code:

```
ftb2.gwy_strt_tmsp >cast((current_date -extract(day from current_date)) as timestamp(6))))
```

This report runs on the 1st day of the month.  I don"t understand the date criteria being used.  Does this code mean that it subtracts the day of the month from the current date to find a date? Any explanation as to what this line of code is doing would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for the help.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `extract(day from current_date)` gets the current day of the month.

Subtracting this from the current date produces the last day of the previous month.

The comparison `>` says "any date matches that is after the last day of the previous month".  Assuming `gwy_strt_tmsp` has no time component, and no timestamps are in the future, then this is a shorthand for "get me records in the current month".

If `gwy_start_tmsp` has a time component, then it would also get records from the last day of the previous month.

Comment: @Shaves - Be sure to accept the answer as correct if it addressed your question.

Comment: I meant to do it yesterday but it was too soon.  It kind of slipped my mind after that.  I try to mark them as answered because I appreciate the help on this site.  Thanks.